# Why does a long long int have the wrong value when initialized with a huge integer literal?

Tags: c, long-integer, literals, integer-overflow

I am trying to store `10000000000000000000` (10<sup>19</sup>) inside a `long long int`.

```cpp
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long long int       intmaximum_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long int   intmaximum_t;
#endif

const intmaximum_t  = 10000000000000000000;
```

But it is giving output `-8446744073709551616`.

I have a 64-bit machine running Ubuntu. How do I store this value?

Comment: this code is not producing any output, please provide a [mcve]. And please choose one language. C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Output depends on proper format specifier. You do not show any function call to `printf` at all.

Comment: instead of `unsigned long int` and `long long int` try `unsigned long long`.

Comment: 2^63 = 9.22 * 10^18. So why were you expecting a predictable result? I would rather expect the compiler to warn you that the number can't fit. Read compiler warnings, do the math.

Answer (score 4):

The largest possible value for a 64 bit `long long int` is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. Your number is bigger than that. (Note that this number less the one you get is one off the number you actually want - that's not a coincidence but a property of 2's complement arithmetic).

It would fit in an `unsigned long long int`, but if you need an `unsigned` type you'll need to use a large number library for your number, or `int128_t` if your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The value 10000000000000000000 is too large to fit in a signed 64-bit integer but will fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.  So when you attempt to assign the value it gets converted in an implementation defined way (typically by just assigning the binary representation directly), and it prints as negative because you are most likely using `%d` or `%ld` as your format specifier.

You need to declare your variable as `unsigned long long` and print it with the `%llu` format specifier.

```
unsigned long long x = 10000000000000000000;
printf("x=%llun", x);
```

Comment: wouldn't you also need to specify the literal as unsigned (and preferably long long) as well?  `10,000,000,000,000,000,000ULL`.  I don't think integer promotion will make a signed number into an unsigned number, and since there are no signed types large enough to hold the value, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Constants are implicitly given a type based on their value and representation.  In this case, the constant is implicitly an `unsigned long long`.  No suffix needed.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to checkout on my tests (though it does give a compiler warning with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).  I was sure I'd had an issue a year ago or so where I had to force an integer literal to `ULL` due to not being able to represent the value otherwise.  I'll have to see if I can find the exact usage that drove that necessity.